# multi maven module CI

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to bring out CI/CD for our microservice system. we use maven + git for project management, and jenkins for CI. For example, I created a maven project named A, then created module B1 and B2 under A. while trying to set up CI for project A, I setup a webhook in Gitlab for project A to notify jenkins to build the project automatically while a push event is triggered. However, this will build the whole project A, including all modules of A. How can I do that just build the actual changed module？

Comment: I assume you are using Maven Job Type for this project in Jenkins. There is a checkbox "incremental build" which will handle to build only changed modules...

Comment: thank you very much. I got it.